# Best way to install multiple mysql server on Linux

Tags: mysql

I am having CentOS release 4.7 (Final) which already have mysql installed on it.
I want to use this but do not have credentials to create database and all..
Also it is having some very important databases so I can not even reset password.

I am looking for a way to install new instance of mysql server on this machine.
could anyone please help me in this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-data-directories.html documents the question completely